# How do I configure Xen's virtualization of interfaces (eth0 to peth0)?

Tags: virtualization, xen, alias, ifconfig, eth0

I installed Xen a while ago but had not yet booted up with the hypervisor. Well I did yesterday and all hell broke loose. I completely lost internet connectivity on my server because of Xen.

When I start up my server and `eth0` is not inside of `br0`, Xen tries to virtualize it by renaming it to `peth0` (physical `eth0`), and then it's supposed to create a `veth0` (virtual `eth0`) and rename it to `eth0`, at least according to [Xen documentation](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Networking).

The problem is that it does not bring up an `eth0` and I am left with absolutely no internet connectivity. I have an `eth1` on my server and would like to virtualize that interface **instead** of `eth0`. To do this I placed `eth1` inside of `br0` and `br0` is being virtualized to `virbr0`. How do I stop Xen from virtualizing `eth0` and use `br0/eth1` instead?

Here is what I get from `systemctl -o cat status network.service`:

```
Bringing up lookback interface:  [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  Error: either "dev" is a duplicate, or "virbr0" is a garbage.
ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Failed to bring up peth0 virbr0.
[FAILED]
Bringing up interface eth1:  [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface br0:  [  OK  ]
```

Gotta love that grammar on the second line (this is verbatim down to the spacing).

virbr0 is handled directly by libvirt, which can be seen from either of the replies to [this message](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-xen/2008-March/msg00000.html) as being configured from `/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks`.

Comment: What is your operating system and which XEN-version are you talking about? The network-stack is something that differs from distribution to distribution and then even has differences between major versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I changed these:

```
(network-script 'network-bridge bridge=virbr0')
(vif-script vif-bridge)
```

to these:

```
(network-script 'network-bridge bridge=virbr0 netdev=eth1')
(vif-script     vif-nat)
```

In `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp`, which successfully left `eth0` alone and only renames `eth1` to `peth1` now, and I assume does not bring up a `veth1/eth1` because it is inside `br0`. Then, I renamed `ifcfg-em1/ifcfg-em2` to `ifcfg-eth0/ifcfg-eth1`, and changed:

```
IPADDR0=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
PREFIX0=xx
GATEWAY0=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

To:

```
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
PREFIX=xx
GATEWAY=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DNS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This gave me back my internet and localhost.

You know what the best part of this experience was? I can leave NetworkManager permanently disabled.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is contained in the link you provided: [Setting up bridged networking](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Networking#Setting_up_bridged_networking).

Prior to XEN 4.1 ist was XEN`s role to set up network bridging.

After that the corresponding bridges should be set up with OS means.

BUT: If no bridges are defined during XEN-Startup, it will create a default-bridge (comparable to the previous behaviour).

There is a good reason to put this outside of XEN-control, since there are very complex bonding/VLAN-combinations that could not be covered by the default-scripts. Also the network-stack is different from OS to OS.

I had a similar problem with SLES10 SP4 - where I needed a quite complex network-setup.

So I set up my own init-script in /etc/init.d/ to set up bridging/bonding/vlans.

With SLES11 SP2 it was a piece of cake and could by set up with the OS-`yast2`-command.

With that the bridges are up an running before XEND starts.

Something like this may work for you:

```
XENBRIDGE=/etc/xen/scripts/network-bridge
$XENBRIDGE bridge=br0 netdev=eth1 start
```

Fedora should be comparable to RHEL6 - so perhaps you can use a [network-setup-document](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_network-bridge.html) and integrate your bridging configuration into the normal network-setup, instead (which is the better way to do this).

Comment: Wait, so what file would I put those two lines in, and how do I stop Xen from renaming eth0 to peth0?

Comment: Or better yet, could you provide an example of your init script?

Comment: @NobleUplift the two lines above are an extract from my init-scripts start-method to fit your needs. Bring down your br0 manually and try it on the command-line. If everything looks well, you could use it.